# Divs cannot be made visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a overlay page where I have one parent div and children div like this

```
<div id="completeBlock" style="display:block">
    <div id="id1" style="display:block">
       This is div one
    </div>
    <div id="id2" style="display:none">
       This is div two
    </div>
        <div id="id3" style="display:none">
       This is div three
    </div>
</div>
```

and separate links to show the divs

```
<a onclick=doChangeDiv(id1)>link one</a>
<a onclick=doChangeDiv(id2)>link two</a>
<a onclick=doChangeDiv(id3)>link three</a>
```

My aim is to show one div at a time and make others none.It works fine in all browsers but in firefox
it works for the very first time I open the page.If I close the page and open it again,
the hidden divs cannot be made visible and I got an error "TypeError: can't access dead object"

My jquery script is

```
function doChangeDiv(fromId){
$('#completeBlock').children().each(function() {
        if($(this).css('display') != 'none')
        {
            var hideId = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
            $(hideId).hide();
        }
   });
   $(fromId).attr('display','block');
   $(fromId).show();
}
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/uD9mU/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fromId = $(this).attr("data");
    //alert(fromId);
    $('#completeBlock').children().hide().filter('#'+fromId).fadeIn('slow');
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it works fine.But the thing is I have more than 3 anchor tags with different classes to which I want to bind this click event and some anchor tags to which I dont want to bind this click event.Is there any way to bind the same event to different classes

Comment: If you have anchor tags with classes `a1`,`b1`,`c1` then use `$('a.a1,a.b1,a.c1').click(...);`